# Check the latitude and longitude of user on form

Tags: javascript, php

I'm a beginner in PHP.
I have a problem in a form, i have to verify if the user is sending me an adress of Paris or not.

```
<?php
    $msg="";
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbname");
    if (isset($_FILES["image"]) AND !empty($_FILES['image']['name']))
    {
        $tailleMax = 3097152;
        $extensionsValides = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
        if($_FILES['image']['size'] <= $tailleMax)
        {
            $extensionUpload = strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['image']['name'], '.'), 1));
            if(in_array($extensionUpload, $extensionsValides))
            {
                $newName =  uniqid(mt_rand(1, 5));
                $imageName = $newName.".".$extensionUpload;
                $chemin = "images/".$imageName;
                $resultat = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$chemin);
            }else{
                $msg = "Le format doit être jpg, jpeg ou png";
            }
        }else{
            $msg = "Photo trop grande";
        }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
        $image = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
        $about = $_POST["about"];
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $adress = $_POST["adress"];
        $category = $_POST["category"];
        $latitude = $_POST["lat"];
        $longitude = $_POST["lng"];
        if($longitude > 48.7 and $longitude < 49 and $latitude > 2.2 and $latitude < 2.5){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO paristable 
                                (picture, name, about, adress, category, latitude, longitude) 
                        VALUES ('$imageName', '$name', '$about', '$adress', '$category', '$latitude', '$longitude')";
            mysqli_query($db, $sql);
            $msg = "Envoi réussi";
        }else{
            $smg= "Veuillez rentrer une adresse parisienne";
        }
    }else{
        $msg= "L'envoi a échoué";
    }
?>
```

So I added this line

```
if($longitude > 48.7 and $longitude < 49 and $latitude > 2.2 and $latitude < 2.5){
```

Because when the user post the adress I have a script which come out the latitude and longitude into hidden input. So I tried to check if he is inside Paris or not with this line. Because if the adress is not in Paris, I don't want to send the datas.

Today my form send it anyway, so i guess i have an error in this line. But i couldn't find it.

And here is my script

```
<script>
function showAlert(){
 var getLocation = function (address) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            console.log(latitude, longitude);
    document.getElementById('lat').value = latitude;
            console.log(latitude);
    document.getElementById('lng').value = longitude;
            console.log(longitude);
        }
    });
};
document.getElementById('location').value = getLocation(document.getElementById('adress').value);
console.log(document.getElementById('location').value);
    document.getElementById('lat').value = latitude;
    document.getElementById('lng').value = longitude;
    console.log(document.getElementById('lat').value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try using && instead of and in the condition

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: so you ask users to enter their latlongs then you trust them with what they entered ?

Comment: @trommelaap `AND` === `&&`

Comment: In fact it's a private form on a site. We are going to display 60 000 pictures of Paris during the two world wars. And no, people will not enter their latitude and longitude but only the adress.

Comment: Seems to me your doing everything backwards. You store what they send you and then you check if the lat/long are correct

Comment: @RiggsFolly considering operator precedence, `AND` === `&&` is not really `true` ;-) (Although in this specific case it might not make a difference.)

Comment: @CBroe Ok, point taken

Comment: @CBroe But in this code, it would make no difference, Right?

Comment: You may also have an issue if I send you a picture of London, but say its address is the `bois du boulogne`

Comment: So I have to check directly in my script? I'll edit my post to add it

Comment: why don't you use their IP address? instead of em entering their address? then use the Ip address to find their city?

Comment: the form (and full html) for this is also unknown, and not sure if that failed at all. Do all POST arrays contain value?

Comment: The form works well
People from india can post post a photo if the adress is behind the eiffel tower, so the IP adress don't work

Comment: And I can still post a photo while I'm in South Africa, by entering an address that is in Paris

Comment: Yes exactly, it's to display images from the two world wars on a map

Comment: @AlexandreRoussel try my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because when the user post the adress I have a script which come out
>   the latitude and longitude into hidden input. So I tried to check if
>   he is inside Paris or not with this line. Because if the adress is not
>   in Paris, I don't want to send the datas.

Now that you have the user's Latlongs you can now be able to use google's [geocode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) API to get the name of the city the coordinates are from, then if the city is Paris you can then post or else display the error Also use prepared statements to prevent against sql injections:

```
<?php
$msg = "";
$db  = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbname");
if (isset($_FILES["image"]) AND !empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
    $tailleMax         = 3097152;
    $extensionsValides = array(
        'jpg',
        'jpeg',
        'png'
    );
    if ($_FILES['image']['size'] <= $tailleMax) {
        $extensionUpload = strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['image']['name'], '.'), 1));
        if (in_array($extensionUpload, $extensionsValides)) {
            $newName   = uniqid(mt_rand(1, 5));
            $imageName = $newName . "." . $extensionUpload;
            $chemin    = "images/" . $imageName;
            $resultat  = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $chemin);
        } else {
            $msg = "Le format doit être jpg, jpeg ou png";
        }
    } else {
        $msg = "Photo trop grande";
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    $image     = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $about     = $_POST["about"];
    $name      = $_POST["name"];
    $adress    = $_POST["adress"];
    $category  = $_POST["category"];
    $latitude  = $_POST["lat"];
    $longitude = $_POST["lng"];

    //get geographical info of the latlongs
    $geocode = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' . $latitude . ',' . $longitude . '&sensor=false');
    $output  = json_decode($geocode);
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($output->results[0]->address_components); $j++) {

        $city = array(
            $output->results[0]->address_components[$j]->types[0]
        );
        //get the city name
        if (in_array("locality", $city)) {
            $cityName = $output->results[0]->address_components[$j]->long_name;
        }
    }

    if ($cityName == "Paris") {
        $sql  = "INSERT INTO paristable (picture, name, about, adress, category, latitude, longitude) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $sql);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssssss', $imageName, $name, $about, $adress, $category, $latitude, $longitude);

        if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {

            $msg = "Envoi réussi";
        } else {

            $msg = mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
        }

    } else {

        $msg = "L'envoi a échoué";
    }


} else {
    $msg = "L'envoi a échoué";
}
?>
```

Comment: Exact, It doesn't work for an adress of Barcelona and works for an adress in Paris. Thanks a lot Masivuye